# Remove duplicate rows using MIN() function with GROUP BY and INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I am trying to list the unique/distinct MIN(time) for each person in the 'Results table' while joining the 'Athletes table' but I am getting duplicates.

Here is some sample data (I am running MySql 5.7)

Results Table

`+----------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+-------------+------------+
| resultID | athleteID | eventID | ageGroup | time  |    venue    |    date    |
+----------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+-------------+------------+
|        1 |        10 |       1 | MS       | 10.20 | Tokyo       | 06-06-2019 |
|        2 |        11 |       1 | MS       | 10.24 | London      | 03-08-2019 |
|        3 |        10 |       1 | MS       | 10.20 | Los Angeles | 01-11-2019 |
|        4 |        13 |       1 | MS       | 10.29 | Glasgow     | 28-10-2019 |
|        5 |        14 |       1 | MS       | 10.32 | Oslo        | 16-07-2019 |
|      ... |       ... |     ... | ...      |   ... | ...         | ...        |
|      ... |       ... |     ... | ...      |   ... | ...         | ...        |
+----------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+-------------+------------+`

Athletes Table

`+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------------+
| athleteID | nameFirst | nameLast | gender | dateOfBirth |
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------------+
|        10 | Bill      | Smith    | MS     | 10-11-2000  |
|        11 | John      | Brown    | MS     | 1-08-1999   |
|        12 | Steve     | Jones    | MS     | 16-01-1997  |
|        13 | Alan      | Green    | MS     | 21-07-2001  |
|        14 | Paul      | Black    | MS     | 27-10-2000  |
|       ... | ...       | ...      | ...    | ...         |
|       ... | ...       | ...      | ...    | ...         |
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------------+`

I have tried the following code - which appears to bring the correct results set, but returns duplicate values. Bill Smith ran 10.20 twice but I only need to show one of them.

Have tried using the DISTINCT function on both SELECT's but no luck - so this is what I have:

`SELECT *
FROM results
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT athleteID, nameFirst, nameLast, MIN(time) as minTime
    FROM results
    INNER JOIN athletes USING(athleteID)
    WHERE eventID = '1'
    AND ageGroup IN('MS')
    AND YEAR(results.date) = '2019'
    GROUP BY athleteID

) AS child ON (results.athleteID = child.athleteID) AND (results.time = minTime)
HAVING YEAR(results.date) = '2019'
ORDER BY minTime ASC`

I get this result

`+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------+
| time  | nameFirst | nameLast |    venue    |    date    |
+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------+
| 10.20 | Bill      | Smith    | Tokyo       | 06-06-2019 |
| 10.20 | Bill      | Smith    | Los Angeles | 01-11-2019 |
| 10.24 | John      | Brown    | London      | 03-08-2019 |
| 10.29 | Steve     | Jones    | Glasgow     | 28-10-2019 |
| 10.32 | Alan      | Green    | Oslo        | 16-07-2019 |
|   ... | ...       | ...      | ...         | ...        |
|   ... | ...       | ...      | ...         | ...        |
+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------+`

As you can see, the additional result for Bill Smith (10.20 - Los Angeles) is also showing up. I need this to be omitted and only show 1 result per athlete - as below.

Desired Result

`+-------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+
| time  | nameFirst | nameLast |  venue  |    date    |
+-------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+
| 10.20 | Bill      | Smith    | Tokyo   | 06-06-2019 |
| 10.24 | John      | Brown    | London  | 03-08-2019 |
| 10.29 | Steve     | Jones    | Glasgow | 28-10-2019 |
| 10.32 | Alan      | Green    | Oslo    | 16-07-2019 |
+-------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+`

Any suggestions as to what I could try?

Many thanks in advance ..

Comment: Your inner `SELECT` with the `GROUP BY athleteID` will return one row per athlete.  Your `INNER JOIN` to the `results` table has a condition of `results.time = minTime` which will take care of duplicates, unless an athlete has multiple events with the same `minTime` value, which looks to be the case with `Bill Smith` who has two events with a time of `10.20`.  How do you decide which row to return in this case?

Comment: Wish to return the row that has the earliest date if they are the same (i.e. 06-06-2019 over 01-11-2019) That being 6 June over 1 Nov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have athlete with the same min time in this case you need  the min date too in outer select

```
SELECT  r.athleteID, r.nameFirst, r.nameLast, min(r.date), child.minTime
FROM results r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT athleteID, nameFirst, nameLast
      , MIN(time) as minTime
    FROM results
    INNER JOIN athletes USING(athleteID)
    WHERE eventID = '1'
    AND ageGroup IN('MS')
    AND YEAR(results.date) = '2019'
    GROUP BY athleteID
) AS child ON (r.athleteID = child.athleteID) AND (r.time = minTime)
WHERE YEAR(r.date) = '2019'
GROUP BY r.athleteID, child.minTime
ORDER BY minTime ASC
```

Comment: That looks very promising! - will do some further testing. Back to you soon.

Comment: I think you have nailed that. Giving your solution as the answer. Thanks very much!